# mkdir() and "Time of Check, Time of Use" vulnerabilities

Tags: c, mkdir, secure-coding

Is there a secure alternative to `mkdir()` for C? I am examining some code and notice it is using calls to `mkdir()`. From what I have read on the US-CERT Secure Coding site, use of that function leaves it vulnerable to "Time of Check, Time of Use" (TOCTOU).

**Edit**

From the miniunz.c source for zlib

```
int mymkdir(dirname)
    const char* dirname;
{
    int ret=0;
#ifdef WIN32
    ret = mkdir(dirname);
#else
#ifdef unix
    ret = mkdir (dirname,0775);
#endif
#endif
    return ret;
}
```

The `mkdir`above is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir()` is only [TOCTOU - Time of Check, Time of Use](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/778-BSI.html) when it's preceded by a check to see if the directory exists.

The usage above, in your example, is ok if the calling code does the right thing. Check Zack's comment.

Comment: It might be good to explain *why* this usage of `mkdir` is immune to TOCTOU violations: `mkdir` is specified to fail if the last component of the pathname already exists, same as `open` with `O_EXCL`.  If the caller of this function properly handles failure, things are good.  However, this is just a wrapper to eliminate a difference between Unix and Windows -- we would need to see the calling code to know if the program avoids the common mistake of calling `stat` first and then assuming `mkdir` will succeed.

Comment: I don't believe this is true.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague; a reference to the US-CERT document and some sample code would be nice.

Nevertheless, I bet the answer is [mkdirat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html).